# How to cache asynchronous result for reuse

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function `handle_response` that has 2 outcomes directed using an `if` statement. Here is the code:

```
function handle_response(response) {
    if (response["unlocked"]) {
        activate_slider();
        // ideally reset_slider() comes here
    } else {
        error(response["message"]);
        reset_slider();
    }
}

function activate_slider() {
    setLocked(false);
    setTimeout(function () {
        setLocked(true);
        reset_slider();
    }, 3000)
}
```

I'd like to move `reset_slider()` out from `activate_slider()` and into the body of the `if` statement, so that it becomes analogous to the `reset_slider()` in the `else` statement which reads better. But I'm unsure how to do so because TWO functions depend on `setTimeout` (i.e., if there were just `reset_slider()`, then I'd just put in the `if` body `setTimeout( reset_slider(), 3000)`.

Also suggestions on better abstractions welcome!

Comment: You won't get the exact same code structure because async code is inherently different in its flow. You can pass in the `reset_slider` as an argument to `active_slider` if you wish, so that it can be invoked when ready.

Comment: Or just not worry about it. "if success, activate slider. else if fail, reset slider" reads just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're executing the setTimeOut method, so, an async process will be executed in the future.

**Hence, the only way to extract the call of `reset_slider` is trough callback functions:**

```
function handle_response(response) {
    if (response["unlocked"]) {
        activate_slider(reset_slider); // ideally reset_slider() comes here
    } else {
        error(response["message"]);
        reset_slider();
    }
}

function activate_slider(cb) {
    setLocked(false);
    setTimeout(function () {
        setLocked(true);
        cb();
    }, 3000)
}
```

Comment: The anonymous function is superfluous. Just do `activate_slider(reset_slider)`